# Add Geojson file(Points) and Use it for an Turf analys

Tags: javascript, geojson, turfjs

I need to add GeoJson file by Clicking on this button

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="TxtFile" type="file" class="form-control-file">
</div>
```

and then i write this function to read Geojson File.

```
function GeoJSON() {
        var url = $('#TxtFile').val();
        
        var GeoJsonSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url: url
        });
        
        var GeoJsonLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: GeoJsonSource
        });
        map.addLayer(GeoJsonLayer);
    
        var GeoJsonObjects = GeoJsonSource.getFeatures();
    }
```

finally i want to add an if condition to this buffer function to read that geojson file and do Turf Buffer On that points.

```
function Buffer() {
if (Filefeatures) {
                    buffereFeature = turf.buffer(format.writeFeaturesObject(Filefeatures), Radius, {units: 'kilometers'});
                    //$('#alertbox span').text('aloooo');
                    resultSource.addFeatures(format.readFeatures(buffereFeature));
}
}
```

Thank You for Help.

Comment: What is your question? How does your code run?

Comment: First, User browse a GEOJSON file in local storage.
when User Press Calculate I want to use that file features for an buffer analys

I want to add an source to layer with an local URL, and then get features from that layer and use them for buffer analyze.
but, I found out  that chrome has a problem with local URLs .
Don't know what can do about it...@swatchai